# Expanding regex metachars into character classes

Tags: regex

`\d` can be expanded to `[0-9]` and `\w` can be expanded to `[0-9a-zA-Z_]`. Is it possible to expand `.`, `$`, and `^`? If so, what would those look like in a character class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`^` and `$` don't expand, they mark the beginning and end of the match.

`.` can expand to `[\w\W]` or `[\d\D]` or `[\s\S]` etc, which means all the characters.
`.` captures anything, digits, special chars, letters, spaces, so you would have to make an exhaustive list of chars within `[]` to match them all, or do one of above expression.

it does not make much sense to try to make an expression longer though.

Also for reference, `\w` captures all alphabetic characters, and `\W` captures the opposite so everything that is not alphabetic character, same principle for `\D` `\S`.